# C loop code from assembly

Tags: c, for-loop, assembly, reverse-engineering

I was given this assembly code and a skeleton of a for loop.  I was supposed to fill in the blanks in the skeleton (indicated by "____" here).  I also provided what I am pretty sure is correct but I'm not 100% positive. Here is the assembly:

```
foo:
      pushl %ebp
      movl %esp,%ebp
      movl 8(%ebp),%ecx
      movl 16(%ebp),%edx
      movl 12(%ebp),%eax
      decl %eax
      js .L3
 .L7:
      cmpl %edx,(%ecx,%eax,4)
      jne .L3
      decl %eax
      jns .L7
 .L3:
      movl %ebp,%esp
      popl %ebp ret
```

Pretty simple right? I was also given this skeleton of a function:

```
int foo(int *a, int n, int val) {
  int i;
  for (i = _________; ____________________________ ; i =___________) {
     ;
  }
  return i; 
}
```

Here is what I wrote:

```
int foo(int *a, int n, int val){
    int i;
    for(i = val--; i>= 0 && n != a[4*i]; i = val--){
        ;
    }
    return(i);
}
```

Please let me know if you think this looks right.  Where I think I could've gone wrong is where i is stored.   think it is done with the decl %eax because that is the register that has what is returned and that was given to me in the skeleton.

Comment: `a[4*i]` should be `a[i]`, at least. You also have an extra `&&` where I think you meant to put a `;`.

Comment: The arguments are assigned to registers out of order, so edx is not val.

Comment: Also, did you try compiling your finished code to see if it matches the example?

Comment: Also, you only have two arguments to your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pseudo-code, this is:

```
// ecx <- int *a; edx <- int val; eax <- int n;

n = n - 1;
if (n < 0)
    goto end;

loop:

if (a[n] != val)
    goto end;

n = n - 1;
if (n >= 0)
    goto loop;

end: return; // return n in eax.
```

It's checking if each element in the array `a[n]` is equal to `val`, from `a[n - 1] .. a[0]`. It returns the index of the element where `a[i] != val`, with `i in {n - 1, .., 0}`, or `-1` if all elements are equal to `val`. e.g.,

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0 && a[i] == val; i = i - 1)
```